# Multiple Item Selection ComboBox in Qt 4.8

Tags: qt, qt4

Is it possible to perform multiple item selection in combobox using Qt 4.8?

Comment: How would the combobox then display the selected items in one line? If you need multiselection, then the combobox is a wrong UI widget to use. Consider using a listbox or a drop down menu with check boxes instead.

Comment: Using checkboxes won't cater my requirements.

ListBox can be useful but i am not able to get listbox in design toolbox.

Comment: @Abhishek It's called a `QListView` (or `QListWidget` for basic functionality).

Comment: Perhaps the OP is looking for something like StackOverflow's tag entry, where you see 'objects' in the combobox when multiple are selected, and you get autocomplete for one item at a time.

Answer (score 0):

if using an external library could be an option for you, there is the `qxt` extension which -- among many other very nice things -- has `qxtcheckcombobox` which seems to cover the functionality that you require. See http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/tip/qxtcheckcombobox.html or more generally:  http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/